# Bug with algorithm for determining if app descriptions are written in English

Tags: ruby, nlp, language-detection

We index apps on the Apple App Store but need to filter out ones with descriptions not written in English.

Our current algorithm fails, though. It fails, for instance, in scoring [this game](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/threes!/id779157948?mt=8) as not written in English when it is.

Here's the boolean method and the regex we use to determine if something is considered English or not:

```
  NonEnglishRegex = /[^\040-\176\u2000-\u206F\u2100-\u214F\u2E00-\u2E7F\u3000-\u303F\u00AE\u2605\u272b-\u272e\s]/

  def not_english?(text)
     text.gsub(NonEnglishRegex, '').length.to_f / text.length < 0.95
  end
```

Is there a better way? We're using Ruby.

Comment: Googling for "cavnar trenkle ruby" gets me https://github.com/hashwin/scylla and https://github.com/simplificator/babel. The latter has just a few language models but if all you care about is English and if it's sufficiently accurate, perhaps that is not a problem. However, more models will probably also improve precision.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [WhatLanguage](https://github.com/peterc/whatlanguage/tree/master) gem. [Here's a YouTube demo](https://github.com/peterc/whatlanguage/tree/master). For instance:

```
"This is a test".language   # => "English"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a web service specifically for detection the language of a text. It can tell you whether a language is English or not. You can read more about it at http://www.whatlanguage.net/en/api/language_identification_made_easy . If you have questions, please let me know.

Comment: What algorithm(s) does this solution use?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not disclose this information as it is a proprietary algorithm.